# VBA: How can I organize a 100+ columns table into a one-column list with 2 empty rows between the items of each column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with 100 columns, each column has 8 rows. Example:

| Column 1 | Column 100 |
| --- | --- |
| Abc | 123 |
| Def | 456 |
| Abc | 123 |
| Def | 456 |
| Abc | 123 |
| Def | 456 |
| Abc | 123 |
| Def | 456 |

I would like to organize the 100 columns table into one single column with two empty rows between the items. The result should be as follows:

| Column 1 |
| --- |
| Abc |
| Def |
| Abc |
| Def |
| Abc |
| Def |
| Abc |
| *empty* |
| *empty* |
| 123 |
| 456 |
| 123 |
| 456 |
| 123 |
| 456 |
| 123 |
| 456 |

Any suggestions on how to code it?

Comment: What you show in the desired picture, means the second column content, not 100th... Should this understanding be a correct one? Do you want copying the format of each column, or only the cells value? For only the values, the code will be much faster, not being necessary to involve clipboard... Do all the columns have 8 rows, now and forever? Should the number of rows be a variable able to be updated, if necessary? Do the involved columns have headers?

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru thanks for your reply.  The example shows two columns but in my case, I have a 100 columns table (each column with 8 rows, no headers). I would like to copy just the values. Now each column has 8 rows but in the future, it might be variable

Comment: OK, I will prepare an answer dealing with variable number of rows and columns...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It does not use Clipboard and it should be fast enough. You can configure the number of columns to be processed. The code itself determines the number of rows in "A:A" and **assumes that al the other columns have the same number of rows**:

```
Sub MergeColumnsContent()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, lr As Long, lastColNo As Long, i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
      lr = lastR   'memorize the initial number of rows (in A:A), which must be the same for all 100 columns
  lastColNo = 17   'last column to be processed (merged)
  
  For i = 2 To lastColNo
        With sh.Range(sh.cells(1, i), sh.cells(lastR, i))
            sh.Range("A" & lastR + 3).Resize(.rows.count, 1).Value = .Value
        End With
        lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'recalculate the last row, after copying
  Next i
  'sh.Range("B1", sh.cells(lr, lastColNo)).ClearContents 'uncomment if you want automatically clear the contents of the processed columns
End Sub
```

After running the code and check if it does exactly what you need, you can (now) manually clear the contents of the processed columns. Or clear everything in A:A, **except the first 8 rows**, **uncomment the last code line** and run the code again. Now it will automatically clear the processed columns content (2 to 100)...

Please, send some feedback after testing it.